# python3.6 can not reopen .pyc file with Chinese path

Tags: python-3.x

**run pyc in cmd**

1.with **Chinese** path
py -3.6 "D:\实施项目\牡丹江高分农业示范\资料\clip.cpython-36.pyc"
python: Can't reopen .pyc file

2.with **English** path
py -3.6 "D:\Download\clip.cpython-36.pyc"
program running
Problem reading input

Answer (score 0):

This is because Python's default path encoding on Windows is ASCII, not UTF-8, and therefore Chinese symbols are treated as something like `D:\Ko&z\Za@e -_~u\:;\clip.cpython-36.pyc`, and the NTFS just cannot find such path and results in WinError, which is overlapped by `python: can't reopen .pyc file` in the console window. In fact, you just cannot open `.pyc` files in non-ASCII paths.

---

## Workaround

Move your .pyc file into a directory which does NOT contain non-ASCII characters in its pathname, or create a symbolic link, junction point or a hardlink, to reflect your `.pyc` file into some other directory. But the most preferred way is to rename your pathname into a pathname without any non-ASCII characters, this will help others understand you in the Stack Overflow community

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
But this pyc file can be opened with python3.5. The test has been done. This is result:
>py -3.5 "D:\实施项目\牡丹江高分农业示范\资料\clip.cpython-35.pyc"
program running
Problem reading input

I don't understand the situation....

Comment: @jg The same problem! I'm not sure why the problem is even worse in CPython 3.6, but use my answer to fix the issue.